# Em PHP como calcular um número aleatório?

Tags: php, números-aleatórios, random

Como calcular um número inteiro aleatório entre 1 e 2000 usando PHP, para fazer um sorteio?

```
function random() {
  // codigo
}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a função `mt_rand`

```
$numero = mt_rand(1, 2000);
echo $numero;
```

[Veja mais sobre essa função nesse link](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mt-rand.php)

Comment: eu ia sugerir a rand() mas essa aqui realmente foi uma boa surpresa. não conhecia.

Comment: Pois é, segundo a documentação oficial, é a "versão melhorada"

Comment: +1 A resposta certa desde que não se pretendam usar os resultados para efeitos de segurança (exemplo: criptografia)

Answer (score 8):

As funções [mt_rand()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mt-rand.php) e [rand()](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.rand.php) geram números [pseudo-aleatórios](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gerador_de_n%C3%BAmeros_pseudoaleat%C3%B3rios), os números gerados por estas funções são previsíveis.

Como alternativa podes fazer uso da função [openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-random-pseudo-bytes.php) <sup>(Inglês)</sup>:

> Generates a string of pseudo-random bytes, with the number of bytes determined by the length parameter.

Que traduzido:

> Gera uma sequência pseudo-aleatória de bytes, com o número de bytes a ser  determinado pelo parâmetro de `length`.

#### Exemplo

```
<?php
function random($min, $max) {
    $range = $min - ($max + 1);
    if($range === 0) {
        return $min;
    }
    $len = (int)(log(abs($range), 2) / 8) + 1;
    $num = hexdec(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($len)));
    return ($min + ($num % $range));
}
```

Comment: Só por curiosidade, nessa linha de alternativas ao pseudo-aleatório há esse serviço online http://www.random.org/ que gera números aleatórios a partir de ruído atmosférico (em tese, gerando assim um "aleatório verdadeiro"). Particularmente eu nunca precisei usar (em geral os pseudo-aleatórios são suficientes para os problemas comuns), mas parece bacana - tem uma API HTTP de uso gratuito, mas limitado em número de chamadas diárias ou algo do gênero.

Comment: O uso do `%` aplicado ao `$range` deixa-me nervoso. Se o valor máximo que $num + 1 pode ter não for um múltiplo de $range, então há nºs mais prováveis de aparecerem do que outros (especificamente os nºs mais pequenos).

Comment: @LuizVieira Parece uma ideia boa, mas cuidado: o HTTP não oculta tráfego. Um atacante poderia usar um man-in-the-middle para prever - ou mesmo alterar - os resultados do sorteio. Para ter resultados melhores, deve ser combinado com outras fontes de números aleatórios.

Comment: @luiscubal Muito bem notado. :)

Comment: @LuizVieira No linux você pode usar ler o conteúdo de /dev/urandom para gerar números aleatórios baseados em rúidos afmosféricos:
`file_get_contents('/dev/urandom', false, null, 0, $len);`
Ou mcrypt_create_iv:
`mcrypt_create_iv($len, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM);`

Comment: @Wynn Ótima informação! Não sabia desse uso de ruído coletado de dispositivos, valeu! Aliás, dando uma olhada na Wikipedia parece que há alternativas caso se esteja usando outros SOs (como Windows, por exemplo): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki//dev/random#Other_operating_systems

Comment: Ao leitor interessado, cuidado com confusão de termos. Ruido atmosférico é o ruido captado por circuitos eletrônicos (como transístor com coletor aberto), e outros meios de detecção de flutuação elétrica. Ruído AMBIENTE no caso de muitos geradores usados em pc pode se referir à informação digital coletada nos drivers de dispositivos (ambiente lógico, e não físico), sendo obtido por software, sem eletronica especializada (como o `/dev/urandom` mencionado). (movimento do mouse, tráfego de rede, etc) - Ambos podem ser usados em geradores aleatórios, mas não usam os mesmos princípios.

Answer (score 2):

A melhor opção, no PHP 7 (ou superior), é utilizar o [`random_int`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php):

```
random_int($menor_numero , $maior_numero);
```

Tanto o $menor_numero e $maior_numero incluem eles mesmos, portanto utilizar:

```
random_int(0 , 1);
```

Gerará o número `1` ou `0`. No seu caso, utilize `random_int(1, 2000)`, já que quer algo entre 1 (incluindo o 1) e 2000 (incluindo o 2000).

---

O limite minimo e máximo é definido pela constante: `PHP_INT_MIN` e `PHP_INT_MAX`, que varia de acordo com a plataforma.

---

O [`random_int`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php) é ["criptograficamente seguro"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographically_secure_pseudorandom_number_generator), ao contrário do `mt_rand` ou `rand`.

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar a função [**rand()**](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.rand.php) que por defenição gera um inteiro aleatório.

A sintaxe é

```
rand($MenorNumeroDesejado, $MaiorNumeroDesejado)
```

Comment: Deixe sua reposta mais completa, explique como a função funciona e insira comentário de referência à documentação do [tag:php].

Comment: Melhorei a sua resposta para dar exemplo. Você pode sempre clicar em editar e melhorar. Quanto melhor fôr a resposta mais útil e mais pontuação vai receber.